# Empty login screen with two monitors (lightdm)

Tags: kali-linux, login, xfce, display, lightdm

I'm using Kali Linux 2020.4 with `xfce4=4.16` and `lightdm=1.26.0-7`.

I have two monitors setup: HDMI 1920x1080 (shows up as 2nd, `HDMI1` in `xrandr`) and VGA 1366x768 (shows up as 1st, `DP1` in `xrandr`), using HDMI monitor as primary.

First issue: when `lightdm` login screen shows up after system boot, `lightdm` takes `1920x1080_60.00` resolution, second monitor works in mirror mode with the same resolution but image gets cropped at `1366x768`. Not critical issue but a bit annoying. Probably it's configurable, but I found nothing useful about this on `google`, `stackoverflow`, `askubuntu` and etc.

Second issue: when I click lock button (which calls `xflock4` as far as I know), both screens turn off. To unlock the computer, I move mouse and screens turn on, `lightdm` shows, but nothing like `lightdm` panel on top of the screen, no login form, nothing. Restarting/reloading `lightdm` doesn't fix it, only reboot helps (but then I lose all running apps, they just get forcibly killed). Very annoying issue.

If you want to help, don't focus on the first issue, it doesn't prevent me from working or something like that.

Thank you for answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

I also have a multi-monitor setup (actually 3 monitors: laptop screen + 2 external 4K monitors, but the second external monitor is always ignored on startup), also with different display resolutions. On startup, the screen is sometimes empty: the background is displayed on both monitors (also in mirror mode), but the menu bar and the login dialog do not appear. To avoid this issue, I've added `active-monitor=1` to the GTK greeter configuration file (`/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`). This seems to always solve this issue, and it is compatible with a one-monitor setup. However, there are still display issues when I want to use the menus.

This may or may not work for you (you did not say which greeter you use), but this should at least give you some hint. I suspect that the greeter thinks that there is a second screen (not mirrored), and it displays the menu bar and login dialog there if `active-monitor` is not set.